# how to write a recursive function that sums the integers in a tree?

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree

Write a recursive function TreeSum(T) to add up all the integers in a tree. My test case is

```
TreeSum(set)
```

> 48

where

```
set=[[[[2,1],[3,7]],[1,2]],[[0,6],[[[3,2],[1,1]],[9,10]]]]
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
def TreeSum(T):
     if len(T)==0:
       return 0
     else:
       return T[0] + TreeSum(T[1:])
```

I am getting an error from the return line ("can only concatenate list (not "int") to list"). How can I fix this?
Error:

```
----> 5    return T[0] + TreeSum(T[1:])
      6 
      7 TreeSum(maple)

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Comment: You're making us guess what the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon added error message

Comment: Your test data is a deeply nested list, and your code doesn't have any way of drilling down into nested lists to get at the actual integers.  Try a google search for "python flatten list".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words - in plain English - where the code says `return T[0] + TreeSum(T[1:])`, exactly what do you want to happen, step by step? What is the intended *algorithm*? Next: what does `T[0]` mean in the code? Does that correspond to some part of your intention? Do you see the missing step in the plan?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I want T[0] to return the integer at position 0. This will then be added to each subsequent integer

Comment: Okay, and in your own words, *why do you expect position 0 to have an integer*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@j1-lee had the correct approach, but this is limited in terms of span of the sublists (silently ignoring the items with a position > 1, or failing if one of the first two elements is an integer). You need to apply the recursive function on all sub-elements. One way is to use `map`

*NB. I slightly changed the input to add two more elements to the first sublist*

```
tree = [[[[2,1],1,[3,7],[1]],[1,2]],[[0,6],[[[3,2],[1,1]],[9,10]]]]

def treesum(x):
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        return x
    return sum(map(treesum, x))
print(treesum(tree))
```

Output: `50`

Comment: thanks! is there a built in python function that can be used to count the nodes in a tree?

Comment: Not directly, you either need to write one or use a specialized module like `networkx`